# How can i insert formulas in latex using some kind of references or something like \input "formula1"

Tags: latex

I want to create file with  pack of latex formulas, name them and use references to insert them to my main document. All I came up with is to create a folder, create new file for every formula and use input, but it would be nice to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using macros for your need.
You can define a new macro using `\newcommand{ref}{formula}` where `ref` is the reference you use to invoke it and `formula` is the actual content you want to be used for typesetting.

E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\areaoftriangle}{$\frac{1}{2}\cdot b \cdot h$}

\begin{document}

\areaoftriangle

\end{document}
```